# QGIS Modeller: Use project variable (@project_folder) as default value for file/folder input

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler

To save users having to always navigate long/complex folders to set a path/geopackage storing the output of a tool, is it possible to set the default value of a File/Folder input parameter to be the home folder of the project?

[image: Dialogue]

Comment: The File/Folder input seems to only accept navigation to a default static folder so you can't use an expression such as @project_folder  || '/Constraints/' ||'SSSI.dxf'. In my models the output is specified by the last Algorithm used to create it and those do allow expressions - do you have to create your files up front?

Answer (score -1):

If you check the 'advanced' box in the properties, you can select a file/folder as your default file/folder. [image]

[image]

Comment: The question is not about setting a fixed path as default but setting the default path to be dynamically driven by a variable.